# What is the gettext command's language for jQuery in poedit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, poedit

I am making a pot file where I want the file to scan for gettext keywords in a JS jQuery file. It scans the php perfectly, but the .js file seems not be working. I am wondering if I have actually the extractor setup correct for the command's language. This is what I have:

Language: `JS`
List of extensions: `*.js` 
Command: `‪xgettext --language=C --force-po -o %o %C %K %F`

It scans the file, but nothing is added. What is the language for jQuery?

**To give more information:**

This is an example of the JS file:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if(location.href.indexOf('/<?php esc_html_e('url_page_discount', 'custom-translation-strings' ?>/') > -1){ //rewards
        jQuery('.rs_custom_fblike_button').attr('value', '<?php esc_attr_e('I Like', 'custom-translation-strings' ?>');
        if (jQuery('#menu-item-10159').length){
            jQuery('#rs_friend_subject').attr('value', '<?php esc_attr_e('Discount for an interesting store!', 'custom-translation-strings' ?>');
        }
    }
});
```

I have covered the `esc_attr_e()` in the sources keywords:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering if I have actually the extractor setup correct for the command's language

You don't. The very fact that you're even configuring extraction suggests that you're either using a very old version of Poedit or you're adding custom configurations. In either case, don't: update to the latest, delete or disable all your custom extractors, and let Poedit do its thing with defaults.

> Command: ‪xgettext —language=**C** --force-po -o %o %C %K %F

You're asking Poedit to treat JavaScript files as being written in C. The results predictably follow the [GIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_in,_garbage_out) principle.

> This is an example of the JS file:

You're putting (even PHP!) code into *string literals*. That's a) not going to work and b) cannot have any translatable strings extracted from.

Comment: Poedit is the latest version, yes I have added a custom configuration to see what is going on. The JS file works, no errors, it just shows it in English. I am here to learn, so I will show you a php file where JS is injected and which is working: [http://prnt.sc/sg9485](http://prnt.sc/sg9485). Could you let me know why this does work?